# How to find exact cause of deserialization error from xml to C# object?

Tags: c#, xslt

I am getting an error System.Boolean cannot be null while deserializing xml into C# object. The xml response that I receive is very large and my C# object also has lot of properties. I have received datatype mismatch errors as well before and it is very difficult to find out which property in the class is causing the error. Is there a way to find this?

All the boolean properties in my class are nullable.

Comment: Nullable Bool and Bool are not the same data types. Not even close. About as close as float and bool. So why does it deserialize a nullable bool as a bool?

Comment: I have properties like-public bool? XYZ{get;set;} in my class to hold null incase there is no value in xml and I am using xslt files to deserialize xml to json. The important question here is that is there a way I can find out which property is causing the issue among the hundreds of bool properties that I have in my class

Comment: Maybe you could include the actual exception message you are receiving. If it's a `System.Xml.XmlException` then it has `SourceUri`, `LineNumber` and `LinePosition` properties that tell you exactly where it failed.

Comment: It throws System.Runtime.Serializtion.SerializationException and it gives line number at which exception occured in the code but I have used xslt files for deserialization.